# Jekyll retrieve current tag and build an index

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Hi i started to built something with Jekyll.
Now i want to built a Top-down list where you can navigate through all the posts with the tag the current page uses.

Here how it looks now.

```
  <div class="list-group">
{% assign custom = page.tag %}
{% for post in site.tags.custom %}
<a href="{{post.url}}" class="list-group-item {% if page.url == post.url %} active {% endif %} ">
  {{post.title}}
</a>
{% endif %}
```

I dont know if the assign is used right.

Answer (score 0):

The working code looks like that:

```
  <div class="list-group">
{% assign custom = page.tag %}
{% for post in site.tags.custom %}
{% if page.url == post.url %} //no liquid inside of  attributes
 <a href="{{post.url}}" class="list-group-item active">
{% endif %} 
<a href="{{post.url}}" class="list-group-item">
 {{post.title}}
</a>
{% endfor %} //endif is only for liquids if
```